# How connect points with lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, line

I need to connect points with lines in QGIS. I am in this fresh out so I'm not sure how to do it and I need a little bit help with this. I read several posts and I tried to do something about it but unfortunately did not work out. So I would ask for a hint and error indication at what I do.

First: I have a couple of addresses in Excel (including city, street and number). I used a plugin (called geokoder navidata.pl) to apply them to a .shp file and I added this layer to program. 
And now, I want to connect some of these points with lines to illustrate how someone has moved.

I tried to use several plugins (e.g. PointConnecter, Point2One, Point to path ) but failed every time.

I have about 1300 points and the line should be two times more (connecting will look like: point 1 to point 2, point 2 to point 3; point 4 to point 2, point 2 to point 5 etc.).

[image]

I have attached photo of what I need to do.

I have points (city, street, house number) and and their coordinates (X and Y) on points layer (.shp) and now I need to connect them using lines as follows:

First address -> address of meeting point -> Second address Third address -> address of meeting point -> Fourth address etc.

The meeting point is one point on the map (in the middle).

Could someone please explain to me how to do it, I tried: point2one, PointConnectr. It seems to me that I should do this by points2path but when I want to do, it gives me an error.

Comment: How about creating new shapefile layer (Line) and editing in it and manually draw line connecting the required points?

Comment: I was thinking about it. But I have about 1300 points and the line should be two times more (connecting will look like: point 1 to point 2, point 2 point 3; point 4 to point 2, point 2 to point 5 etc.).

Comment: What's the format of your connectivity data, i.e. the file which says that point1 connects to point2 and so on

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Points2One plugin.`

1. Install this plugin (Plugins->Manage and install plugins)
2. Follow the instructions for the plugin. Make sure to select line.
3. Save as geojson.

I often find I need to smooth my lines after connecting points. For this, search for simplification algorithms.

Comment: The plugin doesn't present in 3.16.0

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou usar o complemento Networks? Você pode instala-lo pelo menu complementos, depois de instalado ele fica no menu processar/caixa de ferramentas.
A página do complemento é: https://github.com/crocovert/networks/

---

## Machine translation

Have you tried using the Networks add-on? You can install it from the add-ons menu, once installed it is in the render menu / toolbox. The add-on page is: https://github.com/crocovert/networks/